# Python Popen to store what command returns

Tags: javascript, python

I am using Popen to call a node command from my python script. Here is the details:

#### python

```
filename = "myfile.json"
p = Popen(['node', './users/create_har.js', filename], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

#### create_har.js

```
const CHC = require('chrome-har-capturer')
const fs = require('fs');

function createHar(logs) {

    const pageIndex = 0
    const initialRequest = logs.find(message => message.method === 'Network.requestWillBeSent' && message.params.documentURL)
    const url = initialRequest.params.documentURL
    const devtools = null 
    const fetchContent = false
    CHC.fromLog(url, logs).then(
    function(resp)
    {
        // Is there a way Popen.communicate() can capture what is returned from here??
        //console.log(resp.log.entries);

    });
}
```

It would be great if this is possible. Because I don't want to create a temp file and refer it from my python code.

So far I have managed to get `console.log` to python but that is not an ideal solution and is trimmed down if the response is too big.

Comment: its unclear  what you want to communicate back, you have an stdout pipe, so printing returns what was printed (you can make the pipe buffer larger if it gets truncated), other alternative are to pass around a file or use something like sockets to have actual communication

Comment: Hi I want to communicate back the `resp`